# Scala string interpolation empty string compile error

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

Why does an empty string with the string interpolation prefix fail to compile when followed by a statement?

For example

```
val test = s""
println("hello")
```

Fails to compile with error

```
error: value println is not a member of String
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value println'?
       println("hello")
```

But the following all compile fine:

---

```
val test = s""
```

---

```
val test = ""
println("hello")
```

---

```
def test() { s"" }
println("hello")
```

---

```
val test = s" "
println("hello")
```

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a parser bug, fixed last January, so this should be ok in the latest 2.11.x releases.

Here's the bug report: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7919.
The relevant comment (by Paul Phillips) is:

> It's losing the newline token after a completely empty
>   interpolated string. If it's `s"1"`, or a semicolon instead of a
>   newline, or two newlines, or a comment after the empty string, it
>   compiles.
>
> ```
> class A {
>   s""
>   5
> }
> ```

Here's the PR that fixed it: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3411